# How to get users followed/unfollowed time in python

Tags: tweepy

I am trying to get twitter event data and print the time. I have try all possibilities that i can think but it failed. please can anyone help me out

Comment: `Sitestream != sitestream`. Your error and your code do not match up.

Comment: Hi R Nar,I have already tried all the possible cases i.e sitestream and Sitestream it does not work.